# Get first Monday after certain date?

Tags: android

If my app received a certain date, how can I find out the date of first next Monday?

For example, I get the date 28 Sep 2011 and I have to find out the date of the first Monday after this date.

Comment: You can use use Calendar class for that BTW how you want to pass the date?

Comment: This question seems to crop up a lot.. why is that?

Comment: Passing data is irrelevant as I already set up the alarm service. I just need to find out the first Monday to set the alarms in the right manner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do like this:

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar( year, month, day ); 

while( date.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) != Calendar.MONDAY )
  date.add( Calendar.DATE, 1 );
```

You can now extract the year, day and month from date. Remember that month is 0 based (e.g. January = 0, Febuary = 1, etc.) and day is not.

Comment: FYI: this code uses the old legacy date-time classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )                   // Capture the current date as seen by the people in a certain region (time zone).
         .with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) ) ;  // Move to the following Wednesday.
```

## Avoid .Date/.Calendar

The java.util.Date & .Calendar classes bundled with Java/Android are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

## java.time – `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

### Time zone

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

The time zone is crucial in determining the day and day-of-week. Use [proper time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never the 3 or 4 letter codes.

If you ignore time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone will be applied implicitly. This means different outputs when moving your app from one machine to another, or when a sys admin changes the time zone of host machine, or when any Java code in any thread of any app within the same JVM decides to call [`setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-) *even during* your app‘s execution.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### `TemporalAdjuster`

Use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) to get next day-of-week. We can use an implementation in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) (note the plural 's') class: [`next( DayOfWeek )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#next-java.time.DayOfWeek-). Pass an object from the handy [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

```
LocalDate nextWednesday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) );
```

If you wanted today to be found if it is a Wednesday, then call the similar adjuster [`TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

---

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. This section left intact as history.

Here is example code using Joda-Time 2.7.

Get the time zone you desire/expect. If working in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), use the constant `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
```

Get the date-time value you need. Here I am using the current moment.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now( zone );
```

Specify the future day-of-week you want. Note that Joda-Time uses the sensible # 1 for first day of week, rather than zero-based counting found in java.util.Calendar. First day of week is Monday, per international norms and standards (not Sunday as is common in United States).

```
int dayOfWeek = DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY;
```

The `withDayOfWeek` command may go back in time. So we use a [ternary operator (`?:`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to make sure we go forwards in time by adding a week as needed.

```
DateTime future = ( dateTime.getDayOfWeek() < dayOfWeek )
        ? dateTime.withDayOfWeek( dayOfWeek )
        : dateTime.plusWeeks( 1 ).withDayOfWeek( dayOfWeek );
```

You may want to adjust the time-of-day to the first moment of the day to emphasize the focus on the day rather than a particular moment within the day.

```
future = future.withTimeAtStartOfDay(); // Adjust time-of-day to first moment of the day to stress the focus on the entire day rather than a specific moment within the day. Or use `LocalDate` class.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "Next day # " + dayOfWeek + " after " + dateTime + " is " + future );
```

When run.

```
Next day # 6 after 2015-04-18T16:03:36.146-04:00 is 2015-04-25T00:00:00.000-04:00
```

## `LocalDate`

If you only care about the date without any time of day, you can write similar code with the [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class rather than `DateTime`. The "Local" means the date could apply to any locality, rather than having a specific time zone.

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( 2011 , 9 , 28 );

int dayOfWeek = DateTimeConstants.MONDAY;
LocalDate future = ( localDate.getDayOfWeek() < dayOfWeek )
        ? localDate.withDayOfWeek( dayOfWeek )
        : localDate.plusWeeks( 1 ).withDayOfWeek( dayOfWeek );
```

When run.

```
Next day # 1 after 2011-09-28 is 2011-10-03
```

Answer (score 1):

Get Next Monday from the date given.

```
  //code provided by MadProgrammer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177516/get-first-next-monday-after-certain-date/24177555#24177555

  Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
  date1.set(2014, 05, 12);

  while (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {

    date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

System.out.println(date1.getTime());
```

Which outputted...

```
Mon Jun 16 16:22:26 EST 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed [Lamma](http://lamma.io) which is designed to solve this use case. Simply call `next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)` on `io.lamma.Date` object will return the next Monday.

```
System.out.println(new Date(2014, 6, 27).next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));   // Date(2014,6,30)
```

Comment: The project looks cool. Where do you suggest we use it? For what types of apps it's designed for?

Comment: Thanks. The project is designed for complicated date calculation and schedule generation. But not for time or timezone related calculations.

Answer (score 0):

you can use strtotime():

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "Next Monday", strtotime('28 Sep 2011')) );
```

Comment: strtotime()..is'nt it php?